# Why this javascript does not work at all?

Tags: javascript, html, function

**I don't know what's the problem but this piece of code doesn't work on my computer. I've copied it from a course that I've attended to(complete web developer course). This works fine on the course but not with me. Please someone tell me whats the problem i'm stock.**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Learning Javascript</title>

 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />



 </head>

 <body>

 <button id="textChanger">Change first div text</button>

 <div id="firstDiv">This is some text</div>

 <button id="textAppender">Append some text</button>
 
 <div id="secondDiv">Javascript is...</div>

 <button id="textCreator">Create some text</button>

 <div id="emptyDiv"></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 document.getElementById("textChanger").onclick=function() {

 document.getElementById("firstDiv").innerHTML="This is
awesome!";

 }
      
     document.getElementById("textAppender").onclick=function() {

      
document.getElementById("secondDiv").innerHTML=document.getElementById("secondDi
v").innerHTML + "great!";

     }
      
     document.getElementById("textCreator").onclick=function() {

       document.getElementById("emptyDiv").innerHTML="<ul><li>Cat</
li><li>Dog</li></ul>";

     }
 
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "piece of code doesn't work" - have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Add any errors that you have or anything that went wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something was just wrong with your formatting. If you look at the strings some of the text is not recognized as a string.

Check out this edited JavaScript

```js
document.getElementById("textChanger").onclick = function() {

  document.getElementById("firstDiv").innerHTML = "This is awesome!";

}

document.getElementById("textAppender").onclick = function() {


    document.getElementById("secondDiv").innerHTML = document.getElementById("secondDiv").innerHTML + "great!";

}

document.getElementById("textCreator").onclick = function() {

  document.getElementById("emptyDiv").innerHTML = "<ul><li>Cat</li ><li>Dog</li></ul > ";

}
```

```html
<button id="textChanger">Change first div text</button>

<div id="firstDiv">This is some text</div>

<button id="textAppender">Append some text</button>

<div id="secondDiv">Javascript is...</div>

<button id="textCreator">Create some text</button>

<div id="emptyDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the code is just how you've pasted it here, you have line breaks in it that are causing errors.  Pressing F12 in Chrome or FF will open the console and point you to the errors.

In this case, look at lines 32, 40, and 47.

Once you fix that, it works exactly as you have it.